# how do i add syntax highlighting in slack for a new language

Tags: slack

When I create a snippet in Slack, I have to option to apply syntax highlighting to the text by selecting from a long list of "built-in" languages.

How do I add syntax highlighting for my own language within Slack?

Answer (score 0):

Slack uses the open-source [CodeMirror 5.60.0](https://codemirror.net/5/) library for its snippet editor, as disclosed [here](https://slack.com/libs/webapp). The process to add another language would therefore probably look a bit like this:

1. Write a [mode](https://codemirror.net/5/mode/) for CodeMirror 5 and a [language package](https://codemirror.net/examples/lang-package/) for CodeMirror 6 that can highlight your language.
2. Have the CodeMirror maintainers merge your code into an upcoming release.
3. Wait for Slack to update their dependency on CodeMirror to either new version.

This will take some time and a lot of effort. It may not be worth it if there are not many users of your language.